# How can I realize beforehand that I need to use DISTINCT in my query?

Tags: sql

Suppose, I have an SQL problem like the following:
[image]

I have written the following SQL query:

```
SELECT BARS.bar
FROM SELLS JOIN
     BARS
     ON BARS.bar = SELLS.bar JOIN
     DRINKS
     ON DRINKS.drink = SELLS.drink
WHERE BARS.address = 'Nowowiejska' AND
      DRINKS.type = 'Mineral Water' AND
      SELLS.price < 3
```

But, after running the query against a real database, implemented in MS SQL Server, I found that, there are some duplicate bar-names. So, I fixed my query using DISTINCT. But, it was not possible for me to realize the duplication before actually implementing the query in the actual database.

My question is, How can I realize that I need to use DISTINCT in my query?

Comment: Honestly, to know if you need distinct, I would test without distinct (like you did) or if you have access to the actual tables you are pulling the data from, you can check by hand.  Otherwise, if this is not possible, it doesn't really hurt to just include it regardless

Comment: A bar can sell multiple types of mineral water. This is common in the real world and allowed by your schema.

Comment: Learn proper explicit `join` syntax.  Then, you rarely need `select distinct`.  That often indicates a problem with `join`s, which is more likely without explicit `on` clauses.

Comment: Adding it "just because" actually can be harmful - it may force the server to sort all the data and look for duplicates, when it isn't required, which wastes time and resources.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, `SELECT BARS.bar 
FROM (SELLS JOIN BARS ON BARS.bar = SELLS.bar) JOIN DRINKS ON DRINKS.drink = SELLS.drink
WHERE  BARS.address = 'Nowowiejska'
AND DRINKS.type = 'Mineral Water'
AND SELLS.price < 3`    is giving me the same result.

Comment: regardless of the distinct issue....... please read your assignment carefully. it should be an 'OR' and not an 'AND'.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Agreed, however, in this case, it appears that DISTINCT is required in order to avoid getting multiple returns for bars that are on the desired street AND offer the desired drink for less than the desired price.  Please feel free to correct my answer if I'm wrong.

Comment: @anonymous Please remember to upvote any answers that helped you and to accept the answer that best answers your question.  This helps future users more easily find the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you just need to be aware of the cardinality of the relationships between your tables. In your example, if you want a result set that contains at most one record per bar, then you need to be aware that joining the `BARS` table to any other table that may contain multiple records for a single bar (e.g. `SELLS`) can also potentially produce multiple records for the same bar in your result set.

That said, I strongly agree with Gordon Linoff's comment on your question: if you structure your joins properly, I suspect that you will almost never have to use `DISTINCT`. I write a fair amount of SQL and I use `DISTINCT` so rarely that when I see it, I will typically review the query carefully to see whether it's really needed or whether it was used as a "hack" to cover up some incorrect joins.

There's a thing called a *semi-join* that's useful for problems like the one you're working on: where you want to query some table (`SELLS`) to see whether some particular data is present but don't actually need to return it. This is implemented in SQL Server by the keyword `EXISTS`. Here's an example of how you could use it for your problem:

```
-- Sample data from the question:
declare @Bars table (Bar varchar(32), [Address] varchar(32));
declare @Drinks table (Drink varchar(32), [Type] varchar(32));
declare @Sells table (Bar varchar(32), Drink varchar(32), Price money);

insert @Bars values ('A', 'Nowowiejska'), ('B', 'Oak Creek'), ('C', 'Greenfield');
insert @Drinks values ('San Pellegrino', 'Mineral Water');
insert @Sells values ('B', 'San Pellegrino', 2.99), ('C', 'San Pellegrino', 3.50);

-- List bars whose address is Nowowiejska or which sell mineral water for < $3.
select
    B.Bar
from   
    @Bars B
where
    B.[Address] = 'Nowowiejska' or
    exists
    (
        select 1
        from
            @Drinks D
            inner join @Sells S on D.Drink = S.Drink
        where
            S.Bar = B.Bar and
            D.[Type] = 'Mineral Water' and
            S.Price < 3
    );
```

You can read an excellent introduction to joins [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/07/19/671712.aspx) and more about `EXISTS` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

To know if you need to use DISTINCT, you need to know if your joins will produce duplicates, which means you need to understand how they work.

First, you need to read the question more carefully.  It is asking for a bars that are on 'Nowowiejska' street **AND** bars that sell 'Mineral Water' for < 3.  Since you are only using AND in your query, you will only get bars that are on 'Nowowiejska' street **AND** Sell 'Mineral Water' for < 3.

Here is what your query should look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sells.bar
FROM Sells
LEFT OUTER JOIN Bars
    ON Sells.bar = Bars.bar
LEFT OUTER JOIN DRINKS 
    ON Sells.drink = Drinks.drink
WHERE Bars.address = 'Nowowiejska'
OR 
    (
        Drinks.type = 'Mineral Water'
        AND
        Sells.price < 3
    )
```

Note the structure of the where block - which will allow **BOTH** bars that are on 'Nowowiejska' street **AND** bars that sell 'Mineral Water' for < 3.

Since it is possible for a bar to have an address of 'Nowowiejska' **AND** to have a 'Mineral Water' drink for less than 3, you need to allow for **BOTH** possibilities.  By using left outer joins, you will get all bars, all addresses and all drink types and prices.  The where clause then filters your result set to the desired criteria.  Finally, DISTINCT ensures that when a bar matches both joins, you will only get it once.

In short, use DISTINCT when it's possible that a "hit" will either match multiple criteria that are separated by OR - or when it's possible that a "hit" will match multiple records in one of the joining tables.  Since one bar can't have multiple stored addresses on one street - and since one bar can't have multiple identical drinks stored (and if either of these is true, you should immediately fire your DBA and/or developers), you won't get multiple records from the individual joins, themselves.  However, it is entirely possible that a bar can be on the desired street and offer the desired drink for less than the desired price - and you don't want those bars returned twice.

I hope this helps and please feel free to comment if you need clarification.

**EDIT**

It is also possible to simply combine the two (essentially separate) queries with a union.  I would recommend against doing this, since it's better to consolidate queries when possible, but I thought including this might help you better understand how the joins work.

```
SELECT Sells.bar
FROM Sells
JOIN Bars 
    ON Sells.bar = Bars.bar
WHERE Bars.address = 'Nowowiejska'

UNION

SELECT Sells.bar
FROM Sells
JOIN Drinks
    ON Sells.bar = Drinks.bar
WHERE Drinks.type = 'Mineral Water'
AND Sells.price < 3
```

Note that using

```
UNION ALL
```

preserves duplicates, while using

```
UNION
```

does not.

Answer (score 1):

The way to know if you require distinct in your query, which IMO is not common, is to understand what constrains the rows in the tables to be unique, and following from that what effect your joins will have relative to that uniqueness.

Example: if I select bars from a bars table and the table constrains them to be unique, then by definition I never need DISTINCT for that select.

However, if I join that set to another table, then the join logic enters into the problem, and I have to understand the effect of the join on how many values are generated.

Lastly, separate the idea of an actual join ( `tablea inner join tableb on ...` ) from an existence check aka semi-join ( `from tablea where exists ( select * from tableb ...)` ). It's very common for people starting out to write an inner join, which fetches ALL the matches, where perhaps they only needed to check if rows exist, which does not. If you rely on inner join for this, then you will get more rows than you probably need, and may end up with DISTINCT as a workaround - though EXISTS would be better performing and also eliminate the need for DISTINCT in the first place.

Example, bars that sell mineral water might be something like `bars where exists ( select * from drinks ... where <some criteria> )`

Aside: count() is also a poor substitute for exists(), in many cases, just to test if there are any matching rows.

Answer (score -3):

> My question is, How can I realize that I need to use DISTINCT in my query?

```
IF EXISTS(
SELECT BARS.bar
FROM SELLS, BARS, DRINKS
WHERE  BARS.bar = SELLS.bar
AND DRINKS.drink = SELLS.drink
AND BARS.address = 'Nowowiejska'
AND DRINKS.type = 'Mineral Water'
AND SELLS.price < 3
GROUP BY BARS.bar
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT DISTINCT_OR_NOT_DISTINCT ='You need DISTINCT here'
ELSE
SELECT DISTINCT_OR_NOT_DISTINCT ='You dont need DISTINCT here'
```

Comment: This restates the question; it's not an answer.

Comment: Care to elaborate? English is not my native language.

Comment: The top panel of this page is for the question, the entries at the bottom of this page are supposed to be answers to the question

Comment: @onupdatecascade this is an answer to the question. It would work (first do a query to see if there are duplicates and then branch to a version with or without distinct accordingly) though not something I suggest doing.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood.

Comment: This is incorrect and should be down-voted.  This is giving you the answer of whether or not to use DISTINCT based upon the data - and not its structure, which is entirely incorrect.  The decision whether or not to use DISTINCT should be based upon the POTENTIAL for duplicates, not the CURRENT EXISTENCE of duplicates.  Big difference!  Don't do this!